# How to debug html2pdf.js behavior (or reproduce CSS of exported PDF)?

Tags: css, html2pdf

I'm trying to export PDF document with `html2pdf.js` and whole text of PDF is out of alignment.

Here is how text looks inside HTML:

[image]

And here is a PDF version:

[image]

All graphical elements are in place but all texts are shifted down. And here is no way to check CSS parameters for printed out PDF document. So, actually, I'm pretty confusing how to create reproducible example and make this question more focused, because I mixed two huge CSS files. One from separated single HTML page that I'm trying to print and second CSS file is a global styles of `Vue.js` application. So I think that here is multiple not correct inheritances that may break styles.

So here are multiple possible answers that should help me to understand root of problem:

1. AFAIK `html2pdf.js` ① creates clone of DOM element, ② converts it to PDF, ⓷ remove cloned element. Is it possible to store DOM element and prevent deletion of it to be able check styles with browser developer tools?
2. As I said before, all elements alignment is correct. Affected thing is text only. How this behavior may be reproduced?

For example element of black `テスト` text is a simple `div`:

```html
<div style="display: inline-block; padding-bottom: 2px; border-bottom: 4px solid #000000;">
  テスト２
</div>
```

Black bottom line is a `border-bottom`, the only way to cross the border that I found is to change `line-height` to lower value, but in this case text will be shrinked vertically. But inside PDF text is shifted. How it possible to reproduce this behavior without changing `div`s paddings and margins? Only text should be moved.

Also function to convert `HTML` into `PDF` is pretty simple:

```js
import html2pdf from "html2pdf.js";

...

html2pdf(this.$refs.htmlElement, {
  margin: 3,
  filename: "output.pdf",
  image: { type: 'jpeg', quality: 0.98 },
  html2canvas: {
    scale: 2,
    useCORS: true,
    width: 1300,
    allowTaint: true,
    // I tried to set it to true, but console logs are empty
    logging: false
  },
  jsPDF: {
    format: 'A4',
    orientation: 'landscape',
    unit: 'mm'
  },
  enableLinks: false
});
```

#### Additional info (2023/04/18)

We are using `tailwind` as main CSS library inside `Vue` application. After removing [`@tailwind base;`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/preflight) ([code](https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@3.3.1/src/css/preflight.css)) from CSS file text position is printing correctly. But I still can't figure out what part of `tailwindcss` is conflicting with my own styles...

#### Additional info (2023/04/20)

I found CSS parameter that breaking text alignment:

```css
img {
  display: block;
}
```

If I set **globally** `display: unset;` for `img` element PDF text is printing correctly.
However, if I try to change parameter only for current page using [`scoped`](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html) keyword the PDF is generated not correctly again.

I tried to remove all images before generate PDF:

```js
window.document.querySelectorAll('img').forEach( el => {
  el.remove();
});
```

But even if here is no one `img` element in page text is printing not correctly. Can't figure out how `img` style may affect page without `img` elements...

Comment: if possible use tables to get more accurate results. otherwise you need to give height width of the elements.

Comment: @Dakshank `height` should change size of whole `div`, but only text is shifting. Green square and bottom line seem like at correct place. So not sure if here is bad `height` inheritance.

Comment: can you provide a working snippet or external fiddle to understand how its works.

Comment: @Dakshank not sure if it possible... I have to insert single static HTML page with ~500-lines of separated CSS into working `Vue.js` application based on `tailwindcss`. So I don't understand what part of CSS is conflicting to be able provide it as reproducible example. Currently I'm trying to understand what CSS parameter it may be.

Comment: @Dakshank Or If you mean "how works `html2pdf`". You may check this [readme](https://ekoopmans.github.io/html2pdf.js/) for details. Also I added my javascript function  for exporting PDF

Answer (score 1):

hey i have tried to make a codepen from given reference. And it is working fine as output of on pdf is same as configured in js code.

```js
var element = document.getElementById("print");
var opt = {
  margin: 1,
  filename: "myfile.pdf",
  image: { type: "jpeg", quality: 0.98 },
  html2canvas: { scale: 2 },
  jsPDF: { unit: "in", format: "letter", orientation: "portrait" }
};

html2pdf(
  element,
  {
    margin: 3,
    filename: "output.pdf",
    image: { type: "jpeg", quality: 0.98 },
    enableLinks: false
  },
  opt
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2pdf.js/0.10.1/html2pdf.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/1.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
<div id="print">
  <div id="print" style="display: inline-block; padding: 12px; background-color:darkgreen; color:white; font-size: .8rem">
    Title
  </div><br>
  <div id="print" style="display: inline-block; padding-bottom: 2px; border-bottom: 4px solid #000000;">
    テスト２
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/dakshank/pen/PoyzXVX

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. Yes, `html2pdf` is working well. Here is problem in my styles. I added info in question that we are using `tailwindcss` as default CSS library and CSS for single page that I'm trying to print is set mostly manually. I tried to change your example by adding `tailwindcss` stylesheet as default style but it is also working well. And I still can't precise the problem root to be able provide compact piece of reproducible code

Comment: By the way, here are three duplicated ids `id="print"` in your example ;)

Comment: thanks for pointing out ID duplication :D